# Fail to create Excel file from MS Access 2007

Tags: vba, ms-access

Im getting the error

```
Object type argument for the action or method is blank or invalid
```

Don't really understand why as the code Im using works in another database. Here's the code:

```
'Print the report
Private Sub printReport()

        Dim myReport As String
        Dim oXL As Excel.Application
        Dim oBook As Excel.Workbook
        Dim oSheet As Object

        DoCmd.SetWarnings False

        myReport = "\Desktop" & "Report_" & (Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd")) & ".xls"

        If GetVersion = "11.0" Then
            DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, qryTest, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, myReport 

        ElseIf GetVersion = "12.0" Then
            DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, qryTest, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, myReport 

        Else
            DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, qryTest, "Excel 97 - Excel 2003 Workbook (*.xls)", myReport 

        End If

        Set oXL = New Excel.Application
        oXL.Visible = True
        Set oBook = oXL.Workbooks.Open(myReport )
        Set oSheet = oXL.ActiveSheet

        With oBook.ActiveSheet.PageSetup
            .CenterHeader = "Hep C New Patient Report " & (Format(Now(), "m/d/yyyy"))
            .CenterFooter = "&P"
            .PrintTitleRows = "$1:$1"
            .PrintTitleColumns = "$A:$A"
            .Orientation = 2    '1 = Portrait, 2 = Landscape
            .LeftMargin = 18    '72 = 1 inch
            .RightMargin = 18
            .TopMargin = 54
            .BottomMargin = 54
            .PrintGridlines = True
            .PaperSize = 1      '5 = Legal, 1 = Letter
            .ORDER = 2          '2 = Over then down, 1 = Down then over
        End With

        oSheet.Cells.Select
        oSheet.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
        oBook.Save

        oXL.Visible = False

        If (MsgBox("Is it OK to close the report and return to CPE Application?", vbYesNo)) = vbYes Then
            Set oBook = Nothing
            Set oSheet = Nothing
            oXL.Quit
            Set oXL = Nothing
        Else
            MsgBox ("Close Excel when finished to return here.")
            oXL.Visible = True
        End If

        DoCmd.SetWarnings True

End Sub
```

Any ideas?

P.S. It said the error was being generated from the Else statement code

Comment: which else? you've got 2 there.

Comment: The error is being thrown by "Excel 97 - Excel 2003 Workbook (*.xls)" I think.  What are you trying to achieve with this line?  If you want a 2003 file format of .xls you could try acFormatXLS.

Comment: its in the else statement performing the "Excel 97 - Excel 2003 Workbook"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it was getting the error is because the qryTest, the query it will use to fill the excel sheet, wasn't in quotation marks i.e. "qryTest." This is necessary